# Connect to Microsoft SQL Server from IntelliJ (Community Edition)

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 14 and I'm trying to connect to it using IntelliJ but I can't find any option to do so as suggested [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html).

I found [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000411990-Database-option-not-available-under-View-Tool-Windows-in-Intellij-v2018-1-Community-Edition-) that the 'Database tool' is not available in the Community edition so I've downloaded the 'DB Browser' plugin for IntelliJ but it doesn't list any option of 'Microsoft SQL server'.

Is there any way to accomplish this in the Community edition of IntelliJ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box database support is available only n Ultimate edition.